# Actualizar y Eliminar a la vez (EF, Many to Many)

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

¿Qué tal? Tengo una API hecha con `.NET Core API + EF` donde tengo una relacion `many to many` entre `Doctor` y `Especialidad`, de ello surge una tabla `DoctorEspecialidades`. Es decir, un médico puede tener varias especialidades.

Las consultas y demás, las hago desde `React JS`, lo que planteo hacer, es tener en la interfaz, una tabla con las especialidades del médico elegido y cuando envíe el formulario, se actualice o elimine los datos en la tabla `DoctorEspecialidades`.

Si el usuario eliminó o agregó `especialidades`, se podrá hacer todo eso en un solo envío ??

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi duda va mas en como hacer eso en el `Controller`. Espero me puedan ayudar por favor, muchas gracias.